# Conjunction to express extension (of area) "In Moscow and also in the whole Russia there are..."

Tags: word-requests

What conjunction could be used to express extension (of area):

> In Moscow and also in the whole Russia there are lots of folk festivals being held.

So I need construction for: "In A **and also** in the whole B ..."

> 在莫斯科(而且?)在全部俄罗斯有很多民间节日.

Comment: alternative E: "just as in (the whole of R)" 跟全部俄罗斯一样

Comment: You can say "在莫斯科以及全俄罗斯。。。".

Comment: @user6065 , in the "A跟B一样" there is no difference between A and B, they are the same. I need to express precedence of A, but also mention that B is a kind of A.

Comment: 在莫斯科并在全部俄罗斯也有。。。In Moscow, and in all of Russia, too ...

Answer (score 2):

莫斯科 ~ 俄罗斯

> 由莫斯科(**以至**)全俄罗斯 = From Moscow (**to**) the entire Russia
>
> *look at Moscow first, and then extend your view to look at the entire Russia*

*You cannot reverse the order and write "由全俄罗斯(**以至**)莫斯科" because 莫斯科 is already included in 全俄罗斯*

songyuanyao wrote:

> "在莫斯科(**以及**)全俄罗斯

It means "In Moscow (**and also**) the entire Russia" .

*Mainly indicate things happen in Moscow. Mentioning of Russia as a supplementary information. You cannot reverse the order and write "在全俄罗斯(**以及**)莫斯科" because 莫斯科 is already included in 全俄罗斯*

Usage difference between 以至 and 以及:

- "From Boston, New York, Chicago **以至** the whole America" sounds natural. You are extending your view from one city to another and eventually extend to every city in the country
- "In Boston, New York, Chicago **以及** the whole America" sound strange, It is easier just say "In the whole United States"

Answer (score 0):

In Moscow, as in other parts of Russia, there are many folk festivals.
在莫斯科和俄罗斯其它地区一样有很多民间节日。